# How to have text wrap around an image?

Tags: html, css

What's the best approach to achieve the following effect?

[Image Removed by Poster]

I need that text to wrap around the image, which should always be in the bottom right corner. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually is is possible if you're not opposed to non-semantic markup.  Take a look at this working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/chprpipr/Zhz2v/

If you set the background image of the container to contain your portrait image, you can get pretty close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

you will not succeed on this with pure html/css but if javascript is an option for you might want to have a look at

- http://code.google.com/p/jqslickwrap/
- http://www.webappers.com/2008/01/10/css-text-wrapper-makes-hthml-text-wrap-in-shapes/

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you won't be able to get text to wrap around an image like in publishing software and your example above. What you can do is set the image to float to the right or align to the right and assign margin left to it which will pad the text off of it.

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2bjn3/

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. HTML and CSS has some limitations. This cannot be achieved with CSS or HTML.